# Multiclass classification LSTM keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf.keras

I'm stuck in writing keras code for multiclass classification problem. I will expose my problem.

I have a dataset in a single csv file which has rows in the following form

```
1.45    -10.09  1.02    1   0   0   0
```

the first 3 columns represent X,Y,Z accelerations that comes from an accelerometer. The last 4 columns represents class labels. I have 4 classes

```
[1 0 0 0][0 1 0 0][0 0 1 0][0 0 0 1]
```

each vector is a class label that correspond to a single gesture (shaking hand, rotate hand, lift hand, none-of-the-previous)

What i want is to have an LSTM that look back at the previous N steps (let's say 20) taking as input N 3D vectors [X,Y,Z] and at the end of each sequence (composed by these 20 3D vectors) spits out the probability of that sequence to belong to any of the four classes that i have.

Question1: From my understanding the model should be "many to one", am i right?
Question2: how can i implement such network using keras API for python?

i'm really new in coding with keras and what i have done so far is this fragment of code (i'm working in colab):

```
    # load dataset
    from google.colab import files
    uploaded = files.upload()
    
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['data_new.csv']), header=None)
    
  
    dataset = dataframe.values
    X = dataset[:,0:3].astype(float)
    Y = dataset[:,3:].astype(int)
    print(X.shape)
    print(Y.shape)
    model = Sequential()
    ...
    ...
```

the output of the print statements are:

```
(48886, 3)
(48886, 4)
```

I'll post here also some lines of the dataset:

```
1.45    -10.09  1.02    1   0   0   0   
1.06    -10.13  1.06    1   0   0   0   
1.22    -10.09  1.02    1   0   0   0   
1.38    -10.05  1.06    1   0   0   0   
1.03    -10.25  1.18    1   0   0   0   
0.04    -10.17  1.11    1   0   0   0   
0.55    -9.57   1.30    1   0   0   0   
1.18    -9.38   1.26    1   0   0   0   
2.36    -9.22   0.35    1   0   0   0
...
...
```

do i have to reshape input in some way?i'm really stuck, please help me

**EDIT**
I'm trying with the following code using the real dataset

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['data_new.csv']), header=None)

#dataframe = pandas.read_csv("iris.data", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:,0:3].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,3:].astype(int)

X_train = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=-1)


BATCH_SIZE = 20 
EPOCHS = 2 # Used less epochs for testing purposes

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
print("Fit the model on training data")
history = model.fit(X_train, Y, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)

sample_input = np.random.randint(0,100, size=(20, 3))
print(sample_input)
sample_input_reshaped = tf.expand_dims(sample_input, axis=1)
print(sample_input_reshaped.shape)
predictions = model.predict(sample_input_reshaped)
print('Model predictions', predictions)
```

and i am getting this error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_11: expected shape=(None, None, 1), found shape=(None, 1, 3)
```

Comment: yes! exactly :) how to code this?

Answer (score 1):

I made some dummy data based on the input shape of the data you have and ran the model that you would need for it. You can have a more complex model than this but for starters this is sufficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Dummy data 
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(48886, 3)), columns=list("ABC"))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(48886, 4)), columns=list("abcd"))
assert X.shape == (48886, 3)
assert y.shape == (48886, 4)

# You would just need to add the code below to yours
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.25)

X_train = tf.expand_dims(X_train, axis=1)
X_test = tf.expand_dims(X_test, axis=1)

BATCH_SIZE = 20 
EPOCHS = 2 # Used less epochs for testing purposes

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
print("Fit the model on training data")
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)
print(f"History: {history.history}")
print("Evaluating on test data")
results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)

sample_input = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(20, 3))
sample_input_reshaped = tf.expand_dims(sample_input, axis=1)
predictions = model.predict(sample_input_reshaped)
print('Model predictions', predictions)
prediction_class = tf.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
print('Class of predictions', prediction_class)
most_frequent = np.bincount(prediction_class).argmax()
print('Most frequent class: ', most_frequent)
```

**Output:**

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 100)               41600     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 100)               10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 404       
=================================================================
Total params: 52,104
Trainable params: 52,104
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Fit the model on training data
2021-07-08 21:23:52.292396: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
History: {'loss': [4.253803730010986, 7.2851409912109375], 'accuracy': [0.25578224658966064, 0.24983635544776917]}
Evaluating on test data
612/612 [==============================] - 1s 964us/step - loss: 15.3499 - accuracy: 0.2468
test loss, test acc: [15.3499116897583, 0.24676811695098877]
Model predictions [[6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.8483874e-03 9.9284607e-01 3.0563556e-04 2.0347565e-08]
 [6.7954701e-03 9.9290127e-01 3.0327393e-04 2.0033218e-08]
 [6.7954701e-03 9.9290127e-01 3.0327393e-04 2.0033218e-08]]
Class of predictions tf.Tensor([1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1], shape=(20,), dtype=int64)
Most frequent class: 1
```

Comment: ok....first of all thanks a lot! you saved my life actually. Second, let's say i have a sequence of 20 3D vector with no labels, how can i test if that sequence is correctly classified and print out the probability of each class? Moreover, what is the purpose of the expand_dims function?

Comment: @MatteoSirizzotti I updated the answer now it makes predictions on some random 3D vector and outputs the raw predictions and the class with the best prediction. `tf.expandDims()` takes the 2D input you have and adds a dimension making it 3D which is what is needed for an LSTM. You have to do this when making predictions as well, the sample data is `(20,3)` and then it becomes `(1,20,3)` you could even use `tf.reshape(1, 20, 3)`.

Comment: so let me check if i have understand properly: each vector printed out represents the probability of each sequence of 20 3D vectors to belong to each classes. But in this way, i'm seeing that you have generated 100 random samples of dimension (20, 3). So i should have 5 vectors of probabilities (100/20 = 5 sequence of lenght 20 of 3D vectors). What i am confusing?  p.s. you are the best!!

Comment: EDIT in the main answer, i'm getting an error

Comment: @MatteoSirizzotti you need to split the dataset into train and test portions follow the code I have added. Actually I am generating a matrix of size `(20,3)` with values randomly from 0 to 99, so the prediction on this produces a matrix of size `(20,4)` where each row contains the probabilities of each class based on the index.

Comment: ok, but in this way i have a prediction foreach triplette. I need instead a prediction after 20 triplette

Comment: @MatteoSirizzotti ok I am not exactly sure about getting a single class from the model, but a hacky way is to get the most frequent class from those 20 predictions and considering that as the predicted class, I added the code in the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!! i'll try to go deep in order to achieve the result of predicting after each sequence of 20 vectors. In the meantime i'll stick with this approach :)